# Create custom <Link> component in my React shared ui library using monorepo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, architecture, monorepo

I am a beginner regarding the architecture of an application and I want to try to build an application using a Monorepo.

I have a small question about a next.js frontend application that uses my ui package made in React that shares components between my different applications using a monorepo architecture.

For info, my project structure looks like this:

```
/project
    - /apps
        - /client (Next.js)
    - /packages
        - /ui-components (React)
```

I need to create a `<Link>` component in my **/ui-components** that can be reused in my **/client** while taking advantage of the navigation functionality offered by next.js.

My question is: Should I install next.js on my **/ui-components** part as well? Wouldn't this cause problems during the build for example or there could be potential duplications or performance issues?

I wondered if it would be possible to install next.js as a separate package in my **/packages** root and use it in my **/client** and **/ui-component** as well as any part that needs next.js features?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to install Next.js on your /ui-components part. You can just install it on the /client part and use it there. You can then just import the components from the /ui-components part into the /client part, and the Next.js navigation will still work. You won't have any issues with build or performance, and you won't have any duplication of code.

Comment: This does not solve my problem, as I would like to create a <LinkCustom> component in my /ui-components that will be reusable in my other applications like /client /admin etc... While taking advantage of the navigation of next.js in the <LinkCustom> component

Comment: What you can do is create a wrapper component for the <Link> component from Next.js in your /ui-components part, and then import that wrapper component into the /client part. This way, you will have a custom <LinkCustom> component that you can use in all your applications, and you can stil take advantage of the navigation features offered by Next.js.

Comment: So I have to install next.js in my /ui-components ?

Comment: I guess you will have to